# How to pass two variables to a function with decorator

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I have a function ('postcode') that takes input from user and generates two variables that I want to pass to another function ('constituency').

How can I pass two arguments between function such that only one is passed to the url?

```
app("/postcode", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def postcode():
    form = PostcodeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():        
        pc = form.postcode.data.replace(" ", "").strip()
        if validate(pc) == True:
            code, const = dosomething(pc)
            return redirect(url_for('app.constituency', const_id=const)), code

    return render_template("template1.html", form=form)


@app.route("/constituency/<string:const_id>")
def constituency(const_id):
    const = const_id
    people = People.query.filter_by(code=code) # I want the value of "code" here to come from the function 'postcode' above
    return render_template("template2.html", people=people, const=const)
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to pass `code` as a query parameter, or make a new url route that takes a `code` parameter, `url_for` doesn't calls `consitutency` directly, it just generates a url that the browser then requests.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out I can make 'code' a global variable: 
 global code
        code, const = geolocate(pc)
I think this might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: That's not really elegant, a possible solution is to save the code in a cookie